# Laravel 5: Performing an asynchronous task

Tags: php, laravel, asynchronous

I have the following function where I process an image file of type `UploadedFile`, give it as a random name, use `\Intervention\Image` to store it in different sizes, and then return the image name.

The storing part takes lot of time and the request usually times out. It would be great if I could do the processing in a separate thread or process, and return the image name. Here's the code I have:

```
public function storeSnapshots(UploadedFile $image) {
    // Generate a random image name.
    $imageName = str_random(12) . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();

    // Process the image. Should be done asynchronously.
    \Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::make($image)
        ->heighten(2000, function($constraint) {
            $constraint->upsize();
        })->save('img/lg/' . $imageName)
        ->heighten(800)->save('img/md/' . $imageName)
        ->heighten(120)->save('img/sm/' . $imageName);

    // Return the image name generated.
    return $imageName;
}
```

What would be the Laravel way to perform an asynchronous task?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Laravel performs asynchronous tasks via [the queue system](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues).